# Is it possible to make an Indexed View for a particular result I want?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, indexed-view

Is it possible to create an indexed view which returns the following results :-

- ID | Location Name | Aliases for that Location
- 1 | Some Location | Alias 1, Alias 2, Alias 3
- 2 | Another Location | NULL
- 3 | Yet Another Location | NULL
- 4 | Last location | An Alias

My table structure is

Location Table

- LocationId INTEGER
- Name NVARCHAR(100)

LocationAlias Table

- LocationAliasId INTEGER
- LocationId INTEGER
- Name NVARCHAR(100)

and of course, a Location can have 0<->Many Location Aliases

So, can this be done?

Comment: Because i'm not sure HOW to do it .. (yes.. i've tried .. but the subqueries are killing me re: indexing a view).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems highly doubtful that it is possible to index such a view - SQL Server will not allow indexes to be created on views that use subqueries, nor on views that use self-joins (see the docs [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd171921%28SQL.100%29.aspx)) - so I think you're out of luck.